# Can I use a pseudo-selector to style individual words?

Tags: html, css

If i have something like

```
<p id="something">My Text Here</p>
```

Is it possible to use some kind of pseudo-selector in CSS to apply a style only to certain text elements from my text?

Example, i want:

"My" to be color: red;
and "Text" color: blue;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

There are pseudo-selectors such as `:first-letter` and `:first-line`, but you cannot select invidual words without wrapping them in elements that you can individually style:

```
<p id="something">
    <span class="foo">My</span> 
    <span class="bar">Text</span> 
    <span class="baz">Here</span>
</p>
```

You'd then be able to style them individually:

```
.foo {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.bar {
    color: #00ff00;
}
.baz {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i know that if i put classes or ids on my text elements i would be able to do it easily, but in my case that text is a string returned from a php function.
i figured it out eventually, i explode the string and then made it so it automatically adds classes to all the text elements and now i can easily style them.

Answer (score 4):

No. If you want parts of the text to have different colors, you 'll have to wrap them inside separate elements (most likely, ''s). For example:

```
<p id="something"><span class="red">My</span> <span class="blue">Text</span> Here</p>
```

And of course this will also need the appropriate CSS for `.red` and `.blue`.

The exception to the above are the pseudo-selectors `:first-letter` and `:first-line`, but these do not offer any flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first letter pseudo class for styling first letter

```
p:first-letter
{ 
font-size:200%;
color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

But you cant use pseudo class for 2nd "text" you have to wrap this in a html tag & style it separately.

Not possible with Styling words differently.

Answer (score 0):

Other users already told you that it is not possible natively.
If you use jQuery, as I assume from your tag, you can do a little trickery from JavaScript and "tokenize" the text in the `P` tag with:

```
$("p").html($.map($("p").text().split(" ")​,function (i,e) {return "<span id='w"+e+"'>"+i+"</span>";}).join(" "));
```

This command takes a selector (`p` in this case, but you can use `p#myId` and so on) and substitutes every word:

```
 This is a sentence
```

becomes

```
 <span id='w0'>This</span>
 <span id='w1'>is</span>
 <span id='w2'>a</span>
 <span id='w3'>sentence</span>
```

So you could use a CSS like:

```
 p span.w2 {color: red;}
```

to color the third word.